# Storing & Processing Numbers in International Number Formats with Spring Boot & AngularJS

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs

I am currently developing a Spring Boot application that is expected to store/show pricing and inventory data. For numeric values, we have been instructed to use the following number formats:

1. Cost Prices upto 4 decimal places in International Format(e.g. 233,445.6700)
2. Selling Prices upto 2 decimal places in International Format(e.g. 23,500.50)
3. Remaining numbers that are not amounts or prices in International Format(e.g. 123,456)

Now, there are quite a number of ways I could go about this. In lists shown in non-editable tables, I have used `DecimalFormat` with the following patterns:

- FOUR_DECIMAL_FORMAT = "###,##0.0000"
- TWO_DECIMAL_FORMAT = "###,##0.00"
- INTERNATIONAL_NUMBER_FORMAT = "###,###"

I am faced with a dilemma when handling these numbers inside a `jQuery-edit-Table` or a regular form. I can show these numbers with the proper formatting using the above mentioned `DecimalFormat` patterns. But, when I receive those numbers, I don't know a approach other than removing the separators from each numeric value and then storing them. I don't want to do that since it seems like a pain to do for every numeric value.

What should be the ideal approach for handling the numbers here?

Comment: Create filters to display desired format. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Custom filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters).

Comment: @georgeawg What about when using table-edit? How do I manage my numbers then?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).